# Flutter: Hot reload and hot restart are not working on android after adding firebase background functionality

Tags: flutter, flutter-platform-channel

Hot reload and restart are not working on Android after adding firebase messaging to the app.

Getting this error:

> Hot Reload Error
>
> reloadSources: (105) Isolate must be runnable
>
> Isolate must berunnable before this request is made

On iOS they are working fine.

Comment: This issue no longer persists with the latest firebase plugin upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Check your import on file if your import like, Most of the time hot reload and hot restart not work because of this issue

```
import 'file:///E:/SelfProjects2/water_my_plants/lib/screens/Homescreen.dart';
```

change to

```
import 'package:water_my_plants/screens/Homescreen.dart';
```